# What is this metal cylinder with a connected wire that i found in my apparement

Tags: wiring

I live in a rental appartement in Sweden, newly renovated, and just above the floor, on the wall, I found a plastic housing. When I removed the housing I found a rather thick, dense, metal cylinder with a non-isolated wire conneted to it that dissapears into the wall. I have no clue what it is.

My initial guess was some sort of sensor (temperature, humidity) but I already have another wireless temperature sensor in my apparement installed by the land-lord. The cylinder does not feel hollow, but rather dense. These is a text around the bottom of the cylinder reading "SWEDEN 1511 T1" and something that looks like a logo (////A or NNA or MWA or something similair)

Does anybody know what this is and if it dangerous to chew on it (mainly thinking about my 6 month old child...)?

Since I have no clue what this is I have a rather hard time putting relevant tags.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What country or region of the world are you located in?

Comment: I am located in Sweden.

Comment: I was thinking temp sensor like a thermal pile used in gas water heaters / furnaces. Other than that I would not have a clue. Can you trace where the wire or tube goes?

Comment: Unfortunaly I can not trace the wire, it dissaperas behind the skirting. Wouldnt a thermal pile require two wires to be usefull? Instead of one non-isolated? It is not near any other appliances in the appartment (I do not find any appliances in the apparment that could possibly require any external sensor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is remote sensor and capillary tube for a nearby radiator or radiant floor circuit's actuator "thermostat".

Example product: Danfoss RA2972 https://store.danfoss.com/en/Heating-and-District-Energy/Radiator-Thermostats/Radiator-Sensors/Room-sensor-mTRV/RA-2000-Sensors/p/013G2972 the product pictures does not show the tube between the actuator and the sensing bulb.

I've no idea whether the gas/liquid filling of the capillary system is harmful or not.

Comment: The fluid inside expands and contracts with temperature - opening or closing the valve it is connected to.

Comment: Thank you. I found a radiator underneeth my sink in the kitchen, where the same wire entered a thermostat at the radiator.